# Passing a variable to JavaScript in echo

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to pass a defined global variable to java script code in echo php.

Below is my code. This is not working. Please help me with this.

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert('.$this->msg5.')'; //not working alert here
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: `echo 'alert("'.$this->msg5.'")'; ` You're welcome

Comment: What is the error which is shown?

Comment: what is the error? what is the output in html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a string at `$this->msg5` you need to use quotes:

```
echo 'alert("'.$this->msg5.'")';
```